# How to read russian text on adobe windows (R plot)?

Tags: r, adobe, multilingual

I m working on R plot with Russian label but on windows (adobe) russian text are not visible. Do i need to install some package to view it.

```
pdf("sample.pdf",width = 6.6 ,height = 4.2,family= "URWHelvetica",  encoding="KOI8-R") 
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5) 
y<-c(2,3,4,5,6) 
xlable<-c("ручка","книга","часы","ложка","смотреть") 
plot(x,y,xlab=xlable) 
dev.off()
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe you can find solution using information in this page about cyrrilic fonts in R plots http://vss.73rus.com/blog/2007/05/20/cyrillic-fonts-in-R-plots/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to label the points. But you're telling R to write what you want as point labels as an x-axis label. `xlab` is the label for the x-axis.

I think you're really just looking for `text()`

Try this instead, for example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5) 
y <- c(2,3,4,5,6) 
xlable<-c("ручка","книга","часы","ложка","смотреть") 
plot(x,y,xlab=xlable)
text(x,y,xlable,pos=c(4,1,1,1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need labels under the x axis, then you need to use axis() function. This should work

```
pdf("sample.pdf",width = 6.6 ,height = 4.2,family= "URWHelvetica",  encoding="KOI8-R") 
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5) 
y<-c(2,3,4,5,6) 
xlable<-c("ручка","книга","часы","ложка","смотреть") 
plot(x,y,xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=1:5,labels=xlable)
dev.off()
```